# How Can I Determine Which ./configure Options are Currently "Activated"?

Tags: installation, automated-install, compilation

I ran `./configure` on a project a long time ago after tweaking multiple options, but now I want to add an option to the rather long list of current options. I do not remember what options I used, so I don't know what options the new command should use. I still have the build directory, and I have not cleaned it, or tampered with it in any way.

Where do I go to either get the exact command, or some kind of indication of what the options I used before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the following while inside your project's directory:

```
./config.status --config
```

Just remember to prepend `./configure`.